# React Native -- TouchableOpacity takes time to navigate

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, touch, touchableopacity

I have created an app in which if I am using TouchableOpacity to perform any action or navigate but the issue is that I need to click button multiple times also it takes time to navigate to next place. I am writing simple piece of code but don't know why it causing this issue. Please help.

Code to navigate to Login Screen

```
 goToLogin = () => {
  navigation.replace('SignIn');
};
```

UI Code

```
 <KeyboardAvoidingView
  style={{
    display: 'flex',
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
  }}
  behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}>
  <ScrollView
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: !darkTheme
        ? Colors.light.backgrounColor
        : Colors.dark.backgrounColor,
    }}>
    <View
      style={{flex: 0.15, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop:height*0.1}}>
      {!darkTheme ? (
        <Image
          source={require('../assets/images/logo.png')}
          resizeMode="contain"
        />
      ) : (
        <Image
          source={require('../assets/images/logo-white.png')}
          resizeMode="contain"
        />
      )}
    </View>


    <View style={{alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center',   flex: 0.875,}}>
    <View
      style={{
        alignSelf: 'center',
       marginTop:height*0.02
      }}>
      <View
        style={{
          width: width * 0.9,
          borderRadius: 20,

          marginHorizontal: width * 0.015,
          marginBottom: height * 0.05,
          padding: width * 0.03,
          shadowColor: '#49494966',
          shadowOffset: {
            width: -9,
            height: -9,
          },
          shadowRadius: 16,
          shadowOpacity: 0.5,
        }}>
        <View>
          <Text
            style={{
              color: !darkTheme
                ? Colors.light.textColor
                : Colors.dark.textColor,
              fontFamily: 'FiraSans-Medium',
              fontSize: 20,
            }}>
            Sign Up
          </Text>

          {/* Your Name  */}
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              marginTop: height * 0.04,
              width: width,
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            {!darkTheme ? (
              <Image
                source={require('../assets/images/name.png')}
                resizeMode="contain"
              />
            ) : (
              <Image
                source={require('../assets/images/name-white.png')}
                resizeMode="contain"
              />
            )}
            <TextInput
              style={{
                fontSize: 16,
                fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                paddingHorizontal: width * 0.01,
                color: !darkTheme ? Colors.light.black : Colors.light.white,
                borderColor: !darkTheme
                  ? Colors.light.textInputLine
                  : Colors.light.white,
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                width: width * 0.75,
              }}
              value={yourName}
              onChangeText={value => {
                setYourName(value);
              }}
              clearButtonMode="always"
              placeholder="Your Name"
              placeholderTextColor={
                !darkTheme
                  ? Colors.light.placeholderColor
                  : Colors.light.white65
              }
              autoCapitalize="none"
            />
          </View>

          {/* Date of Birth  */}

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={showDatepicker}>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                marginTop: height * 0.04,
                width: width,
                alignItems: 'center',
              }}>
              {!darkTheme ? (
                <Image
                  source={require('../assets/images/dob.png')}
                  resizeMode="contain"
                />
              ) : (
                <Image
                  source={require('../assets/images/dob-white.png')}
                  resizeMode="contain"
                />
              )}

              <View
                style={{
                  borderColor: Colors.light.textInputLine,
                  borderBottomWidth: 1,
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                    paddingHorizontal: width * 0.01,
                    color: dateSelected
                      ? Colors.light.textColor
                      : Colors.light.placeholderColor,
                    width: width * 0.75,
                  }}>
                  {dateSelected ? dob : ' Date of Birth'}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          {show && (
            <DatePicker
              modal
              open={show}
              date={startDate}
              mode="date"
              textColor={Colors.light.text}
              display="inline"
              onConfirm={date => {
                setShow(false);
                setDate(date);
                setDateSelected(true);
                setDOB(moment(date).format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
              }}
              onCancel={() => {
                setShow(startDate);
              }}
            />
          )}

          {/* parent name */}
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              marginTop: height * 0.04,
              width: width,
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            {!darkTheme ? (
              <Image
                source={require('../assets/images/parent-name.png')}
                resizeMode="contain"
              />
            ) : (
              <Image
                source={require('../assets/images/parent-name-white.png')}
                resizeMode="contain"
              />
            )}

            <TextInput
              style={{
                fontSize: 16,
                fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                paddingHorizontal: width * 0.01,
                color: !darkTheme ? Colors.light.black : Colors.light.white,
                borderColor: !darkTheme
                  ? Colors.light.textInputLine
                  : Colors.light.white,
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                width: width * 0.75,
              }}
              value={parentName}
              onChangeText={value => {
                setParentName(value);
              }}
              clearButtonMode="always"
              secureTextEntry={false}
              placeholder="Parent Name"
              placeholderTextColor={
                !darkTheme
                  ? Colors.light.placeholderColor
                  : Colors.light.white
              }
              autoCapitalize="none"
            />
          </View>

          {/* Email */}
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              marginTop: height * 0.04,
              width: width,
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            {!darkTheme ? (
              <Image
                source={require('../assets/images/email.png')}
                resizeMode="contain"
              />
            ) : (
              <Image
                source={require('../assets/images/email-white.png')}
                resizeMode="contain"
              />
            )}

            <TextInput
              style={{
                fontSize: 16,
                fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                paddingHorizontal: width * 0.01,
                color: !darkTheme ? Colors.light.black : Colors.light.white,
                borderColor: !darkTheme
                  ? Colors.light.textInputLine
                  : Colors.light.white,
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                width: width * 0.75,
              }}
              value={email}
              onChangeText={value => {
                setEmail(value);
              }}
              onSubmitEditing={() => onEmailSubmit()}
              clearButtonMode="always"
              placeholder="Email"
              placeholderTextColor={
                !darkTheme
                  ? Colors.light.placeholderColor
                  : Colors.light.white
              }
              autoCapitalize="none"
            />
          </View>

          {/* UserName */}
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              marginTop: height * 0.04,
              width: width,
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            {!darkTheme ? (
              <Image
                source={require('../assets/images/username.png')}
                resizeMode="contain"
              />
            ) : (
              <Image
                source={require('../assets/images/username-white.png')}
                resizeMode="contain"
              />
            )}
            <TextInput
              style={{
                fontSize: 16,
                fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                paddingHorizontal: width * 0.01,
                color: !darkTheme ? Colors.light.black : Colors.light.white,
                borderColor: !darkTheme
                  ? Colors.light.textInputLine
                  : Colors.light.white,
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                width: width * 0.75,
              }}
              value={userName}
              onChangeText={value => {
                setUserName(value.toLowerCase());
              }}
              clearButtonMode="always"
              secureTextEntry={false}
              placeholder="Username"
              placeholderTextColor={
                !darkTheme
                  ? Colors.light.placeholderColor
                  : Colors.light.white
              }
              autoCapitalize="none"
              
            />
          </View>

          {/* Password */}
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              marginTop: height * 0.04,
              width: width,
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            {!darkTheme ? (
              <Image
                source={require('../assets/images/password.png')}
                resizeMode="contain"
              />
            ) : (
              <Image
                source={require('../assets/images/password-white.png')}
                resizeMode="contain"
              />
            )}

            <TextInput
              style={{
                fontSize: 16,
                fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                paddingHorizontal: width * 0.01,
                color: !darkTheme ? Colors.light.black : Colors.light.white,
                borderColor: !darkTheme
                  ? Colors.light.textInputLine
                  : Colors.light.white,
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                width: width * 0.7,
              }}
              value={password}
              onChangeText={value => {
                setPassword(value);
              }}
              onSubmitEditing={() => checkPassword(password)}
              secureTextEntry={securePwd}
              placeholder="Password"
              placeholderTextColor={
                !darkTheme
                  ? Colors.light.placeholderColor
                  : Colors.light.white
              }
              autoCapitalize="none"
            />

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setSecurePwd(!securePwd)}>
              {securePwd ? (
                !darkTheme ? (
                  <Image
                    source={require('../assets/images/eye-close.png')}
                    resizeMode="contain"
                    style={{width: 30, height: 20}}
                  />
                ) : (
                  <Image
                    source={require('../assets/images/eye-close-white.png')}
                    resizeMode="contain"
                    style={{width: 30, height: 20}}
                  />
                )
              ) : !darkTheme ? (
                <Image
                  source={require('../assets/images/eye-open.png')}
                  resizeMode="contain"
                  style={{width: 30, height: 20}}
                />
              ) : (
                <Image
                  source={require('../assets/images/eye-open-white.png')}
                  resizeMode="contain"
                  style={{width: 30, height: 20}}
                />
              )}
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              alignItems: 'center',
              marginTop: height * 0.01,
            }}>
            <Text
              style={{
                color: !darkTheme
                  ? Colors.light.placeholderColor
                  : Colors.light.white65,
                fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                fontSize: 16,
                marginRight: width * 0.03,
                marginLeft: width * 0.01,
                textAlign: 'justify',
              }}>
              {strings.tNc}

              <Text
                style={{
                  color: Colors.light.blueColor,
                  fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                  fontSize: 16,
                }}>
                {strings.terms}
              </Text>

              <Text
                style={{
                  color: !darkTheme
                    ? Colors.light.placeholderColor
                    : Colors.light.white65,
                  fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                  fontSize: 16,
                }}>
                {strings.and}
              </Text>

              <Text
                style={{
                  color: Colors.light.blueColor,
                  fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                  fontSize: 16,
                }}>
                {strings.privacyPolicy}
              </Text>
            </Text>
          </View>

          {/* sign Up button */}

          <View
            style={{
              width: width * 0.3,
              height: height * 0.05,
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignSelf: 'center',
              borderRadius: 25,
              marginTop: height * 0.04,
              backgroundColor: Colors.light.buttonBackground,
              marginBottom: height * 0.04,
            }}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                validateSignUp();
              }}>
              <View>
                {!loader ? (
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      color: Colors.dark.textColor,
                      fontFamily: 'FiraSans-Regular',
                      fontSize: 17,
                    }}>
                    {strings.signUp}
                  </Text>
                ) : (
                  <ActivityIndicator color={Colors.light.white} />
                )}
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>

    <View
      style={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flex: 0.07,
      }}>
      <Text
        style={{
          fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
          fontSize: 16,
          color: !darkTheme
            ? Colors.light.placeholderColor
            : Colors.light.white65,
          marginRight: width * 0.01,
        }}>
        {strings.alreadyUser}
      </Text>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={goToLogin}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
            fontSize: 16,
            color: Colors.light.blueColor,
          }}>
          {strings.login}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>

    </View>
  </ScrollView>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Login Button Code

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={goToLogin}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
            fontSize: 16,
            color: Colors.light.blueColor,
          }}>
          {strings.login}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Could anyone please help me in this issue as I got fed up with this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you importing TouchableOpacity from RN or react-native-gesture-handler?  You could try the other one as an option.

Comment: I am facing your issue too. It takes time to navigate to other page. This is releated to the rendering workload in target page. In other words, if your "SignIn" page contains heavy component, it takes time to render (when the TouchableOpacity is showing activeOpacity)  then navigate.

Comment: @PeterTam Thanks for your feedback. Could you please help me what should I do on this?

Comment: You may need to find out which component affect the render performance, try to comment some of them and retry the navigation until the lag is minimized. Since there are many reason to cause this issue, I cannot confirm it must solve the problem.

Comment: @PeterTam ok thank you so much. I will check that.

Comment: can you make a repro GitHub repo for this issue? i will fix it

Comment: I'd suggest you to split your large component in several smaller ones to gain 2 benefits: better readability and more performance, because not the complete component is rerendered once the state changes and instead only the subcomponents, where the change happened, are rerendered

Comment: Hey @deepanshigupta, I see that you are using a lot of images in your UI and directly using require to render it. It would be a most efficient that you make an Images.js file where you can fetch the images using require and save it into a constant and then export it from the file and use the images.

Comment: Agree with @Adnansayed , You can try to compress image size (or just try to remove some picture then check the problem if still exist or not).